# Non editable text in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating a registration form using Kivy. I wants the text in textboxes, which is present when form loads as non-editable. As can be seen from below I can edit "Name" field as "Na". I want that user entering name cannot do a backspace and remove "Name".

[image]

This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import fileinput
import sys
import os


Builder.load_string("""
<Reg>:
    # This are attributes of the class Reg now
    a: _a
    b: _b
    c: _c
    d: _d
    e: _e
    f: _f
    g: _g
    result: _result
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ScreenManager:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            id: _screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: 'screen1'
                GridLayout:
                    cols:1
                    TextInput:
                        id: _a
                        text: 'Name: '
                    TextInput:
                        id: _b
                        text: 'Age: '
                    TextInput:
                        id: _c
                        text: 'Phone: '
                    TextInput:
                        id: _d
                        text: 'Email: '
                    TextInput:
                        id: _e
                        text: 'Address: '   
                    TextInput:
                        id: _f
                        text: 'Guardian Name: '
                    TextInput:
                        id: _g
                        text: 'Guardian Phone: '                            
                    Label:
                        id: _result

                    Button:
                        text: 'Register Me'
                        # Or you can call a method from the root class (instance of calc)
                        on_press: root.genxml(*args)
            Screen:
                name: 'screen2'
                Label: 
                    text: 'The second screen'
""")
```

Answer (score 3):

While you could probably do that, it would be difficult to implement. I would suggest either splitting out that text as a [`Label`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html), or using [`hint_text`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.hint_text) (text which only appears if the `TextInput` is empty and not focused).

Original:

```
TextInput:
    id: _a
    text: 'Name: '
```

With `Label`:

```
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        size_hint_x: 0.4  # adjust as necessary, or use None and set width instead
        text: 'Name:'
    TextInput:
        id: _a
```

With `hint_text`:

```
TextInput:
    id: _a
    hint_text: 'Name'
```